# php regex replace form tag but keep some attributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

hello I have the following code :

```
preg_replace('~<form\s*.*?(?:class="(.*?)"|id="(.*?)")?>~i','<form method="post" class="$1" id="$2">', "from html source code");
```

what I want is if the form tag has class attribute or id in it then they get replaced.

```
<form method="post" class="login-css">
```

so the output of the code above will be :

```
<form method="post" class="login-css" id="">
```

and if the form tag is like this :

```
<form method="post">
```

then output will be:

```
<form method="post" class="" id="">
```

Comment: I didn't quite get it. The HTML is PHP-generated or the PHP will manipulate inputted HTML code at runtime? If it's the first, you don't have to use regex for it, there are other ways to do it, like a simple if statement.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: where is this <form> tag located and how PHP should access it?

Comment: it's located on file_get_contents

Comment: I replace source code that come to me from file_get_contents

Comment: you need javascript for this. `form` is located in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<form method="post"(?: class="(.*?)")?(?: id="(.*?)")?>
```

With

```
<form method="post" class="$1" id="$2">
```

I got a tool (RegexBuddy) that can convert it to php but I don't program into it myself

```
$result = preg_replace('/<form method="post"(?: class="(.*?)")?(?: id="(.*?)")?>/', '<form method="post" class="$1" id="$2">', $subject);
```

I used the following string to test with and it works

```
zer <form method="post" class="a" id="b">  zaer zer <form method="post" class="a">   azerzer
```

In practice you may have to make it a less strict and allow whitespace here and there.